# How to get gps location every 30 mins in the background

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to make an app that will send your gps location to a webserver every x mins. Im confused about how I should do this. Do I use a timer or a different service to call the get gps function every x mins?

This is what I'm using to get the gps signal

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        false);
                LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                };
                try {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0,
                            loc_listener);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is perfect for this. You can have your application request the system to set off the alarm every 30 minutes (either manually each time or with the setRepeating() method). This alarm will go off regardless of whether your application is running at the time or not. You will need a broadcast receiver to handle the intent it generates. There is a good tutorial on alarms [here](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129).

Comment: I have a function called update location. Its actually an async task and i call it using updateLocation().execute(); Should I set an alarm in the oncreate method of my first activity and call updateLocation().execute() from there? Because the example talks about starting a new activity

Answer (score 1):

You should register to the [AlarmManger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start your [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which will get the position and send it to the server.

At the end of your service execution, set a new Alarm for 30 minutes from current time.

Comment: If I begin my alarm in my splash page and it calls itself 30mins from the current time, what happens if I close the app and turn on the splash page once more? Will the timer restart or  will I have two alarms now?